# how vertically align text on one line, if there is one element (text) in the vertical list with an icon on the left

Tags: html, css

maybe someone knows a good way to align the text on one line and shift the icon to the left

### HTML

[image: html]

### CSS

[image: css]

### Screen

[image: screen]

Comment: I can't really understand what you actually need, mind explaining it better?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `position: absolute` to the `pseudo-element` `::before` and use the positioning value `left` to position it however you like. `left: 0` will position it as far away to the left as possible (on top of the `<li>` in this case), so just use a negative value to put it further to the left. Remember to apply `position: relative` on the `<li>`-element as well, so the `::before`-element is positioned `absolute` relatively to the `<li>`-element.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
}

.element::before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>text</li>
  <li class="element">text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```